# What kinds of animations can be exported to SceneKit?

Tags: animation, export, collada

Blender offers many ways to animate a scene, but some of these do not seem to get exported to the COLLADA (.dae) format that can be consumed by Apple SceneKit. Which approaches to animation *can* be exported?